# Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=blockchain-transactions)

Tags: firebase, blockchain

I’ve got an angular/node.js application that uses firebase functions and blockchain in the back end.

I’m getting an error when it tries to add an object to the blockchain:

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=blockchain-transactions)
```

This is coming from this line here:

```
const pubsub = new PubSub();
pubsub.topic(‘blockchain-transactions').publisher().publish(signedBlockTransaction);
```

The call to publish(signedBlockTransaction) is throwing the error.

All I can understand about this error is that it’s looking for a resource called ‘blockchain-transaction’ and it can’t find it. But beyond this, I’m not sure why it can’t find it or how to fix it (I didn’t write the code).

One thing that may be affecting it is the following:

I was dealing with a different error which I managed to get by but I don’t know if I did it the right way. The error was:

```
Cannot read property ‘privatekey’ of undefined
```

…when trying to execute this line:

```
functions.config().blockchain.privatekey
```

It turns out .runtimeconfig.json was empty, literally only containing {}

So in an attempt to give it a private key, I went to my file id_rsa which contain a private key for something or other (I think github) and added it like so:

```
{
    "blockchain": {
        “privatekey": *** my private key ***
    }
}
```

That got me past the first error, but I understood the private key I gave it probably isn’t the one it’s looking for.

So my question is: is the error I’m encountering now a consequence of the wrong private key? If not, what is the cause of the error, and how do I fix it?

Thanks.